# Styling the map to look different

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

How do I style leaflet's map to have different colors?

MapBox allows you to easily change the colors of buildings, streets, areas, waters, and lands.

Believe me, I've googled this to no end. Clearly my google-fu is awful.

Any help/advice would be appreciated on how to change the underlying colors.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the relevant documentation would be [How do I customize my map's colors?](https://www.mapbox.com/help/customizing-map-colors/)

Comment: thanks for the link. However, that applies to MapBox only. My question pertained to Leaflet. I was using MapBox's ability to change colors as an example.

Comment: Leaflet doesn't have its own maps: it's just a container for map tiles.

Comment: hm, so I have to utilize map tiles in order to overlay different colors on the map?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you aren't wanting to overlay anything, just use different map tiles. There are many different tile options for Leaflet, including the mapbox ones you mentioned. Here's a gist that I find helpful: https://gist.github.com/mourner/1804938

And here's an example that shows several basemaps: http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/